# How can we create google chart that is stacked with multiple columns and negative numbers?

Tags: javascript, pandas, react-google-charts, ng2-google-chart

I am trying to create a google chart stacked with multiple columns and negative numbers.

Data:

```
   ['2001', -321, 621, 816, 319],
    ['2002', 163, 231, -539, 594],
    ['2003', 125, 819, 123, 578],
    ['2004', -197, 536, 613, -298]
```

If we replace the data to the **http://jsfiddle.net/p7o0pjgg/**   and remove the below code works but the right and left y-axis is not properly level to 0.

**Is it possible to align the right and left y-axises?**

viewWindow: { min: 0,
max: 1000
}

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
viewWindow: {min: -1000, max: 1000}
```

You can put -1000 or the number you want, but do not erase the line.